# Android - Taking Photos from camera storing photo at 2 paths

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

I am able to save a full-size photo from the camera at the specified location. However, the photo is being saved at 2 paths - one specified by code, second sd card DCIM folder.

Below is the code to get a full-size photo, it is in Activity and fileUri and mFilePath are class level variables.

```
private void openCamera() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        fileUri);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                            REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        }


    private File createFile() throws IOException {

            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            File storageDir;
            if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
            } else {
                storageDir = getFilesDir();
            }
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                storageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            File image = File.createTempFile(“app” + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    ".jpg", storageDir);

            mFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{
                            mFilePath},
                    null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        }
                    });
        }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
    galleryAddPic();
    }
}
```

I am not sure is this device or platform specific. I am testing this on Moto G (2nd generation) and 5.0 Android OS. I have tried changing the storage setting for camera app but it always saves at 2 paths. I don't want it to get save at sd card DCIM folder. Has anyone faced such kind of issue? Any idea how to solve this?

Edit: I tried on Samsung's mobile which has 7.0 OS. There this behavior does not exist. Taken picture is getting save only at the specified path.

Comment: I am following the steps mentioned on the android developer forum. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html. This says the creating file is required if you want to save full-size photos.

Comment: Ignore my comment then, I must be wrong :). On a side note, is your code exactly the same as their example? As their example should be a good way to do it.

Comment: The only difference is, the example is storing pics in app's file directly and I am storing pics in external storage picture directory if sd card is mounted.

Comment: This is happening in Moto devices I have checked on other company devices like Samsung and google it is not creating two images. Does anyone find a solution to it.